# BFS backtracking - the case of isolated clusters

Tags: graph, pseudocode

I have written pseudocode for BFS for backtracking to see whether a graph is two colorable or not. Now I want to include the case that the graph might not be connected, i.e. that there might be isolated clusters (in this case of students). What would be the best way to achieve that? My thinking is that I need to loop over each component in the graph, but I don't know if that is correct and how that should be written into the code

```
# node = student
# edges = relation
function insert_edge(adj[], node i,node j, visited, color) 
   adj[node i] add node j
   adj[node j] add node i 

function bipartite_graph(adj[], node j,visited, color)
   for each node i in adj[node j]
      if node i not visited 
         mark node i as visited  
         color of i != color of j
         if not bipartite_graph (adj, node i, visited, color)
            return false 
       else if color of i == color of j
          return false 
    return true

function main()
   Initialize number of vertices
   Initialize vector adjacency list adj
   Initialize vector visited
   Initialize vector color
   Insert edges to graph

   Mark source node with color
   Mark source node as visited

   if bipartite_graph (adj[], node j,visited, color)
      return "Yes"
   else do 
      return "No"
```

Comment: How do you select the source node?

Comment: I haven't specified it cause I don't really know how I would do it

Comment: Well, once you figure that out, keep doing it until there are no unvisited nodes left.